# How to detect j2me memory leak?

Tags: memory, java-me, symbian, memory-leaks

everyone

I development j2me mobile application base on Symbian platform.

Develop tool :eclipse and eclipse me plug

I think that my application has memory leak.But i do not know which code make it.
Anybody tell me that is there tool to detect memory leak for j2me application?
   thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can activate the profiler for your JavaME emulator. That would give you the information about the objects in memory and the methods that created them.

Comment: I don`t know how to profiler JAVAME emulater.
Give me some information?